# Adding elements to a form using JQuery causes the "The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted" error on submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I have an MVC App, with a regular form that includes `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, however i have a javascript function, with JQuery .append() call that adds elements to the form, am using this function to include elements in which shall act as hiddenfor() elements within the form and values shall be serialized to the corresponding Post Controller method on submit, 
as described below:

```
$('#DivHiddenAccountsSub').append("<input id=\"LstAccountsSubDisplay_" + objAccountSub.ID + "__ActId\" name=\"LstAccountsSubDisplay[" + objAccountSub.ID + "].ActId\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + objAccountSub.ActId + "\" />");
```

However, when i hit the submit button i get the following error:
"The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster,

Note: The above listed code, after replacing the objAccountSub.ID, shall look something like: `<input id="LstAccountsSubDisplay_0__ActId" name="LstAccountsSubDisplay[0].ActId" type="hidden" value="01001" />`

How can i append elements to the form without breaking the AntiForgeryToken() value??

Answer (score 0):

try to create the element first then append it as the following:

```
 $('#DivHiddenAccountsSub').append($("<input id=\"LstAccountsSubDisplay_" + objAccountSub.ID + "__ActId\" name=\"LstAccountsSubDisplay[" + objAccountSub.ID + "].ActId\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + objAccountSub.ActId + "\" />"));
```

Comment: Tried the above solution but still the same error is displayed upon submit

Comment: check if the  AntiForgeryToken() is applied twice in the same form

Comment: Nop, only once, made sure of it